# Using Hintpath on x86 and x64 machines

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

On my 64 bit machine I created a a project that as a reference to a DLL

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\Libraries\Server\System.ServiceModel.PollingDuplex.dll

If I open that project on my x86 machine, that reference will fail, because the directory is really "C:\Program Files"

Is there a way to do this so it works in both enviornments?

Answer (score 3):

Use the environment variable property $(ProgramFiles)

```
$(ProgramFiles)\SDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\Libraries\Server\System.ServiceModel.PollingDuplex.dll
```

That did it.

Answer (score 1):

If you analyze it carefully, you can simply put that dll in your code base under a common third party library folder, such as lib. Then there is even no need to install Silverlight SDK if you are working on this WCF project.